# Mixing functions and subpackages in Python packages

Tags: python, python-module

Is there a way to mix subpackages and functions in my Python packages?

Currently, my layout is roughly like this:

```
lib/
   __init__.py
   Transform.py
   Statistic.py
```

where `Transform.py` and `Statistic.py` contain several functions each. To use them I do something like

```
from lib import Transform

Transform.fft(signal);
```

Now I would like to be able to have a function in a package inside `Transform`:

```
from lib.Transform import bins

Transform.bins.extent(signal);
```

Is that even possible? How would I have to define my packages to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution #1:** Try the following layout:

```
lib/
  __init__.py
  Statistic.py
  Transform
    __init__.py
    bins.py
```

In this case `Transform.fft` goes inside `lib/Transform/__init__.py` and `Transform.bins.extent` inside `lib/Transform/bins.py`

**Solution #2:** If you wish to keep `__init__.py` short and clean, you can also create a separate Python-module (like `fft.py`) and import it in `__init__.py` as follows:

```
from fft import *
```

In which case you can also use:

```
from lib.Transform import fft
```

Comment: Ah! I thought `__init__.py` was only for stuff like `__all__ = [...]`.

Comment: Nope, it's for all code. However, as a convention, you may not want to put too much stuff inside `__init__.py`. See the edit for details.